# Unity 2d not able to addforce diagonly

Tags: unity-game-engine

Have 'PlayerMovement' and 'PlayerOnTrigger' script added to the main player. This is my 'PlayerOnTrigger' script code and the problem is even though I set the knockback diagonally, it just keep jumping vertically.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerOnTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement pm;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        //pm.gameObject.layer = 9;
        int dirc = pm.transform.position.x - collision.transform.position.x > 0 ? 1 : -1;

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(dirc,1) * 3, ForceMode2D.Impulse);      //keeps jumping, not knockbacking
        }
    } 
}
```

I tried debugging the Vector2 inside the addforce and it is showing the correct value. what am I stuck on? is it the problem of some components?

Comment: 3kg of force is not a lot

Comment: Player's mass is 1kg so it's enough and problem is that I can see player getting knock backed vertically, simply jumping upward when colliding "enemy". So I thought I have a problem with the dirc but it wasn't. I tried debugging dirc but was showing the decent value. Guessing the problem is with the collider so I tried applying box,circle,capsule 2dcollider but the results were all the same.

Comment: @BugFinder also big thanks for replying all of my questions. It means a lot to me

Comment: no but 3kg is not a lot, depending on the speed, mass * speed  and all that physics crap i have forgotten cos its > 35 years since I was at school. You are not only needing to counteract that momentum forward, but send it back

Comment: I tried 100kg but it will only effect the y value and can't see any changes on the x. Also tried only giving force on the x vector and it won't move a bit.

Comment: have you considered just -100* rb.velocity  - making sure nothing in update/fixed update is overriding it and pushing it back forwards

Comment: if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(100, 3), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

I typed this at the very top of the update method but still showing the same result. I haven't set the freeze position y so have no idea what's going on

Comment: so something you are doing is overwriting it later.... only you can work that out = NB I said "-100*rb.velocity" eg 100* the speed you came in at back the way you came

Comment: I had problem with the fixed update code. it was keep overwriting and couldn't find it cuz I didn't capsize it good enough. Thanks!!